# how to display data in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I am retrieving an address from the database and displaying this address on page. The issue or problem that I am facing is the the way the retrieved address is being displayed.

Basically this is the way the address is being displayed:

```
Address:  1 Kings Street Kilmarnock East Berkshire Scotland KA1 UIT
```

I would like the address to be displayed like so:

```
Address:  1 Kings Street
Kilmarnock
East Berkshire
Scotland
KA1 UIT
```

How can I do this in HTML or css?  I am currently using twitter bootstrap , and I don't if there is anyway to do using it.

Comment: Does the original data have a newline in it, where you want to break?

Comment: Good luck parsing unstructured data like that. You should consider refactoring your database and break each aspect out into its own attribute. Regarding your question: you don't say what backend systems you're working with nor did you tag them.

Comment: Including the actual HTML used to display this data is an important part of being able to answer your question.

Comment: I'm just giggling to myself at the address to be honest, as Berkshire (near London) is apparently in Scotland. As for the question, however, you'll need to have either split the address in your db, or creating some sort of universal way of deciding to put an 'escape like' character into it to represent a newline. All current answers are simply not taking into account that the info is taken from a database.

Comment: If the address stored in the database does have line breaks couldn't you just wrap it in a `<pre>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.. It's hard but let me try... ;)

```
<div>Address:  1 Kings Street<br> Kilmarnock <br>East Berkshire<br> Scotland <br>KA1 UIT</div>
```

**Your Expected Output:**

```
Address: 1 Kings Street
Kilmarnock
East Berkshire
Scotland
KA1 UIT
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xgzbr647/2/)**

**Note:** This is just simplest and basic way.. But if Data is coming from any database dynamically then at-least you should explain in details from where it comes and by which object it can be accessible.. Then you can apply `JS` or `regex` functions... I hope you understand what I mean..

Comment: +1 for the fiddle, and because you're 4pts away from 1k.

Comment: @DavidT : Thanks... Finally I cross 1k bcz of u.. You have a big contribution.. I appreciate ;)

Comment: I was debating it anyway, but as you were 4pts away it sealed the deal. :)

Comment: @GaganGami this does not take into account that the info is being taken from a database, and will only work on a predefined string :(

Answer (score 1):

If you edited the data in your database, and used a comma between each line, you might be able to split the data. (your question doesn't state what language you are writing in (mvc/how data is being received).

However, once you have the string, you can use the [String.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method (available in most languages), and hence could adapt your view accordingly.

So,

```
Address:  1 Kings Street, Kilmarnock, East Berkshire, Scotland, KA1 UIT
```

would become

```
{1 Kings Street}{ Kilmarnock}{ East Berkshire}{ Scotland}{ KA1 UIT}
```

which you could then do a `foreach` block, displaying them onto the screen as you requested

---

A **possible alternative** (although probably not easy), would be to extract the postcode, and call a google maps API call to receive the address - but again, this would be quite difficult.

---

At present, I cannot see how you would be able to expect a program to decide where to split the address into separate lines (unless you place them into different fields which was described in the comments).

Answer (score -1):

You can add `<p>` to each line, or put `<br>` at the end of each lines.

But

If your retrieving the data from a database through a php variable you cannot do that with pure html / css, you'll need string manipulation with PHP.